# Is the busybox cpio THAT different from GNU cpio?

Tags: busybox, cpio

I'm trying to do an incremental backup using cpio but it seems that the busybox version doesn't work the same as the normal one? This is what I've got so far:

`find data/Backup -mtime -2 | cpio -cm media/USB_FLASH_2`

I origianlly used:

`find . -mtime -2 | cpio -cm /media/USB_FLASH_2`

However, I've seen people say busybox doesn't like definitive paths while using cpio. Unsure about that though.

It returns an error that basically says I'm using cpio wrong. I can't find anyone using the busybox cpio to do things like this, does that mean i can't do it? I've looked at using rsync as well but again, it doesn't do what i would expect.

For reference I'm using PuTTY to connect through SSH to a ReadyNAS 102.

After using `find . -mtime -2 | cpio -o | { cd /media/USB_FLASH_2 && cpio -imd; }`

i get the output:

```
BusyBox v1.20.2 (Debian 1:1.20.0-7) multi-call binary.

Usage: cpio [-dmvu] [-F FILE] [-H newc] [-tio] [EXTR_FILE]...

Extract or list files from a cpio archive, or
create an archive using file list on stdin

Main operation mode:
        -t      List
        -i      Extract EXTR_FILEs (or all)
        -o      Create (requires -H newc)
        -d      Make leading directories
        -m      Preserve mtime
        -v      Verbose
        -u      Overwrite
        -F FILE Input (-t,-i,-p) or output (-o) file
        -H newc Archive format
```

Answer (score 2):

The options that the `BusyBox` commands have depends *a lot* on the options that `BusyBox` is compiled with. `BusyBox` aims to be highly configurable so that very small cut down versions can be compiled for systems where resources are very limited. Larger, more full featured versions can be built where this isn't an issue.

In your case `cpio` needs the `-p` or `--pass-through` (long form) option enabled. Normally `cpio` behaves more like an archive utility like `tar`, however it also has an extra function which allows it to copy files. To enable this in `BusyBox`, it needs to be built with `FEATURE_CPIO_P` defined (also `LONG_OPTS` for long form options to be enabled for any program).

From your last question, I strongly recommend that you use `rsync` for what you are doing. You are probably better off asking another question detailing exactly what you are doing with `rsync` and why it doesn't do what you expect. `rsync` is an extremely versatile tool and can no doubt be configured to do what you want.

That said, you could try the following with `cpio`, this will create an archive and then extract it again (somewhat less efficient, but still the same result):

```
find . -mtime -2 | cpio -o | { cd /media/USB_FLASH_2 && cpio -imd; }
```

Unfortunately the `-o` option can also be disabled in `BusyBox` (`FEATURE_CPIO_O` build option), so this may not work either.

#### Update

Based on this line of output, you need to add an extra option when creating an archive:

```
    -o      Create (requires -H newc)
```

This changes the command to:

```
find . -mtime -2 | cpio -oH newc | { cd /media/USB_FLASH_2 && cpio -imd; }
```

This time I have tested with the `cpio` in the `BusyBox` for my own system and it works for me, however in some cases the mtimes for directories won't be preserved. `rsync` should be the best way to do this.

Comment: Yes i was aware that -p was the main limiting factor and i'm glad you came up with a solution, i don't get any errors but it looks like it crashes? None of the files that should be copied arent there. I'm all up for using rsync but i'm not aware of how powerful it is, I thought it was like a cp/tar command in one.

Comment: @user62094 Please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/118558/edit) your question an post any output you get. Please remember the `;` (I forgot this at first and edited it in a few minutes later). Also, which shell are you using, the output of `echo $0` should show which one. If you post another question for the `rsync` and add a link here, I will take a look.

Comment: @user62094 updated, you need an extra option.