# Using rsync or cpio to do an incremental backup

Tags: backup, rsync, cpio

I'm trying to do an incremental backup of all files on my NAS box that where modified in the last 24 hours (or so, can be more flexible).

I'm using PuTTY to connect through SSH to a ReadyNAS 102 which has BusyBox v1.20.2 and uses Bash.

I origianlly used:

`find . -mtime -2 | cpio -cm /media/USB_FLASH_2`

And then tried:

`find . -mtime -2 | cpio -o | { cd /media/USB_FLASH_2 && cpio -imd; }`

which got me the error:

BusyBox v1.20.2 (Debian 1:1.20.0-7) multi-call binary.

Usage: cpio [-dmvu] [-F FILE] [-H newc] [-tio] [EXTR_FILE]...

Extract or list files from a cpio archive, or create an archive using file list on stdin

Main operation mode: -t List -i Extract EXTR_FILEs (or all) -o Create (requires -H newc) -d Make leading directories -m Preserve mtime -v Verbose -u Overwrite -F FILE Input (-t,-i,-p) or output (-o) file -H newc Archive format.

Comment: This doesn't add anything new from your last tow questions, as such the answers are largely the same. You say that `rsync` is not working as expected, if you want to get help with it you should *explain* what you have tried and how it doesn't work instead of reiterating what you have already asked.

Answer (score 3):

Great! Rsync is your beast and is is well worth the learning curve, (there are many options). I wouldn't bother with worrying about your *find modified last 2 days requirement* either, since rsync will check for modification (which achieves more or less the the same, cuts down on what is transfered and only copies files that have been updated compared to destination).

```
rsync -va srcdir destdir
```

I added the -v for verbosity only so you can see what's going on. if your were copying remotely (over internet to a remote computer) then --progress will show progress during the copy of each individual file.

If you want to exactly match your directory, ie. if you want rsync to remove files on destination that are no longer on source (because they've been deleted) this is possible as well with `--delete`, but I think you are creating an archive so I didn't use that in the example.

Further options depend on your specific requirements (follow links ? etc). I'll leave that to you to choose `man rsync`

You can give it include lists, exclude lists, as well in case you're copying a development area which might contain backup files from editors.

Summary of archive options

```
-a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
-r recursive
-l copy symbolic links as symbolic links
-p preserve attributes
-t preserve times
-g preserve group
-o preserve owner
-D preserver devices (must be super user to work)
```

If you are copying between machiens then your need to consider time synchronisation or fuzzy time matching but you are copying onto sd card on one computer so no need to worry.

If you really want to use `find` then `rsync` can take a list of files from a file with `--files-from` in which case the -r (recursive) option of archive mode is not respected.

`find . -mtime 2 | rsync -av --files-from - srcdir destdir`

But please read the manual page since `--files-from` has side affects, and I thought there was too much to copy into this answer.

If your destination might be updated somewhere else you can add,

```
-u, --update                skip files that are newer on the receiver
```

Comment: The `-u` option is only necessary if the files at the destination may change - this is usually not the case with a backup. If it is the case, then `unison` is a much better tool to use.

Comment: @Graeme tks have updated to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me where you want the output to go, but:

```
find . -mtime -2 | cpio -co > whatever.cpio
```

Should work. Apparently `-m` "is meaningless with" `-o` (note I don't know why you want `-c` here, but I left it in).  If you want the stuff mirrored to a directory instead (i.e., no cpio file), use `-p` with an argument instead:

```
find . -mtime -2 | cpio -mp /backup/path
```

Comment: The idea here was to create and extract an archive since the OP's BusyBox `cpio` isn't built with a `-p` option. It doesn't work since creating an archive with BusyBox `cpio` needs `-H` too. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118558/is-the-busybox-cpio-that-different-from-gnu-cpio/118561